# Grouped LIMIT based on foreign key in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm having a table like below

student table

```
studentid |  countryid  | cityid
   1             1           1
   2             1           3
   3             2           2
   4             1           1
```

Expected result

```
studentid | countryid | cityid
    1           1          1
    2           1          3
    3           2          2
```

I want to get the list of student records where Ill have maximum of one student per each city and a maximum of two students per each country.
I came across this article, but having a difficulties in implementing it
http://charlesnagy.info/it/postgresql/group-by-limit-per-group-in-postgresql

Comment: Based on your data sample, can you add the exact expected result?

Comment: I have edited question with the expected result

Comment: can you try this? `SELECT studentid,countryid,cityid FROM (
  SELECT distinct
    studentid,countryid,cityid,
    count(studentid) OVER (PARTITION BY countryid) AS qt_country,
    count(studentid) OVER (PARTITION BY cityid) AS qt_city
  FROM t) t2
WHERE t2.qt_country <= 2 AND t2.qt_city = 1;`

Comment: this is trying to fetch studentids with less than 1 cityid and 2 countryids. I want to get the list of students